# LibGdx animation sequence

Tags: android, libgdx, animation

In my game the character movement animations work fine
but now I'm trying to do a sequence of programmatic animations,
for an enemy character, and it's proving to be a pain.

I'm just doing it on Android.

I have the enemy character doing a walking animation till
it reaches and end position, then I want it to do a three frame
throw animation.  It's walk animation is fine.

Since I only want to do the throw animation frames once, I tried to use
`Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL`, and try to use `isAnimationFinished()`.

I also tried to get the frame number using `getKeyFrameIndex()`
to try to detect when it showed the last frame.

But in both cases, when it reaches the end position, either I just
see a flash of one of the throwing frames, or nothing at all,
and it says it's "finished" with the animation, using one of the above
ways to test it.

```
objectBatch.draw(
    animation.getKeyFrame(throwingSkeletonObject.fStateTime),
    throwingSkeletonObject.position.x,  // x
    throwingSkeletonObject.position.y,  // y
    1,      // width
    1);     // height
```

I'm using the `fStateTime` that was passed into the Object from the
`update()` of the Object.  For the walking animation I use:

```
 animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

and for the throw animation:

```
 animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
```

The frameDuration for the walk animation is 0.7f and for the throw 0.3f.

So what do I need to do to be able to actually see
all the frames of the throw animation, and then be able to
tell when that's "finished", so I can go back to the walk
animation going the other way or whatever?

I've tried lots of different combinations of things, including using
a slower throw frameDuration, and nothing seems to really work.

Eventually I want to try to get the Boss animations going
and those are much more complicated, so I want to get
this fairly simple sequence to work.

UPDATE:

In the `update()` I'm doing:

```
throwingSkeletonObject.fStateTime += fDeltaTime;
```

The game is 2D, and I'm not using scene2D.

UPDATE  SOLVED?:

I wrote a smaller test app in hopes of replicating the problem
but it worked pretty well.  When it did the throw animation I reset the
StateTime back to zero, so as a test, I commented that out so it used the
same StateTime as the walking animation and it only showed one
frame of the throwing animation, so I think that was the problem.
But I'm not sure about the throwing animation "end" test, I'm hoping
that that will also work now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the throwing animation is quite simple: timing.

You set the frameDuration to 0.3f. This is (obviously) equal to 3/10f. When you set the frameDuration, it's in terms of seconds per frame. In this case, each frame lasts 0.3 seconds for a total of under a second.

Try setting the frameDuration to 2/3f. That will result in the throw animation lasting almost exactly 2 seconds.